# Create a mapping from dictionary based on the associated value with each value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary of following sort:

```
{ 'Publisher_name': [( 'Sun Publications', '0')],  'Author_Book Ratio': [(1.27364726,  '00')
, (0.765346483,  '01')],  'Book_series_no': [(1,  '000'), (2,  '001'), 
(1,  '010'), (2,  '011')],  'Volume_No': [(1,  '0010'), (2,  '0011')],
'publishing_status': [( 'Y',  '000'), ( 'Y',  '001'), ( 'N',  '010'), ( 'Y',  '011')],  
'Volume_name': [( 'Perils of Annoyance Vol.1',  '0010'), ( 'Perils of Annoyance Vol.2',  '0011')],
  'Book_name': [( 'Thoughts of a River Bound Duck',  '000'),
 ( 'Perils of Annoyance',  '001'), ( 'Welcome to the Valley',  '010'),
 ( 'Open the box',  '011')],  'Author_name': [( 'August Oliver',  '00'),
 ( 'Pierce Rhombus',  '01')],  'Author_ID': [(3,  '00'), (2,  '01')],
  'timestamp': [( '01-Aug-17 13:25:32', '0')]}
```

The accompanying number to each value depicts the level and to which parent the element belongs to. Author details which have '00' denotes it belongs to the '0'th publisher and is the '1'st author and '001'depicts the book belongs to 0th publisher, 0th author and is 0th book of him. All the values are similar. If there is no value for a specific parent node or child node that column would be filled null. I want to create a dataframe from this dictionary which would be of following sort-

```
+----------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------------+---------+
|  Publisher_name|         timestamp|   Author_name|Author_Book_Ratio|Author_ID|                     Book_name|Book_series_no|publishing_status|              Volume_name|Volume_No|     
+----------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------------+---------+
|Sun Publications|01-Aug-17 13:25:32| August Oliver|       1.27364726|        3|Thoughts of a River Bound Duck|             1|                Y|                     Null|     Null|
|Sun Publications|01-Aug-17 13:25:32| August Oliver|       1.27364726|        3|           Perils of Annoyance|             2|                Y|Perils of Annoyance Vol.1|        1|
|Sun Publications|01-Aug-17 13:25:32| August Oliver|       1.27364726|        3|           Perils of Annoyance|             2|                Y|Perils of Annoyance Vol.2|        2|
|Sun Publications|01-Aug-17 13:25:32|Pierce Rhombus|      0.765346483|        2|         Welcome to the Valley|             1|                N|                     Null|     Null|
|Sun Publications|01-Aug-17 13:25:32|Pierce Rhombus|      0.765346483|        2|                  Open the box|             2|                Y|                     Null|     Null|
+----------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: First let us know about your try. Can you share your code with us?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]